# many value of delta corresponding to single epsilon?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, continuity, definition

I have to prove that limiting value of $f(x,y)=xy^2/(x^2+y^2)$ is zero when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ using epsilon delta relation.

My solution is 
$|xy^2/(x^2+y^2)|< |x|< \delta$  as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$
so here I got $\varepsilon=\delta$.
Now I can also take $\varepsilon= n \times \delta$ where $n>1$

In this way I have many value of $\delta$ corresponding to one value of $\varepsilon$. Is that correct ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Right, $0\leq\left|\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq|x|.$

The limite 0 follows immediately from the squeeze theorem. (are you familiar with?)

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention to "using epsilon delta relation".

Comment: This is not answer to the question. The question was *not* how to show the limit but whether one could take $epsilon$ bigger. Therefore Sumit shouldn't have marked this as a correct answer.

Comment: I agree it is not answer to the question. I realized it shortly after posting my answer and wrote that in a comment. Though, my answer can be a mi-step for a successful solution. Therefore I did not delete it. I hope it is not against "be kind" policy.

Comment: My comment/critique was directed more towards Sumit than you, Maam.

Answer (score 0):

The number $\varepsilon$ is fixed from the start. Therefore, you can't take $\varepsilon=n\times\delta$.

On the other hand, if $\delta=\varepsilon$ works, then $\delta=\frac\varepsilon2,\delta=\frac\varepsilon3,\ldots$ will also work. There's no problem there.